# packer + ansible, how to specify the inventory file

Tags: vagrant, ansible, digital-ocean, packer

When I use vagrant, I can specify the inventory file in the Vagrantfile.

Example:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "my_folder/playbook.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "my_folder/inventory_file"
end
```

How can I configure the inventory_file when I use packer?

I can't see any related info in the official documentation of packer:

http://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible-local.html

I need specify the inventory file, because, when I run my packer.json, this is the output:

```
digitalocean: Executing Ansible: ansible-playbook /tmp/my_folder/playbook.yml -c local -i "127.0.0.1,"
digitalocean:
digitalocean: PLAY [foo] ******************************************************************
digitalocean: skipping: no hosts matched
```

Packer seems using a inventory file named "127.0.0.1,", and I don't know why.

How can I specify my inventory file?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the ansible part of your packer.json ?

Comment: "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "file",
            "source": "my_folder",
            "destination": "/tmp/"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "script": "provisioner.sh"
        },
        {
            "type": "ansible-local",
            "staging_directory": "/tmp/my_folder",
            "playbook_file": "my_folder/playbook.yml" # this is a local playbook
        }
    ]

I'm copying my local ansible folder to /tmp/my_folder, and then, i run the ansible, but i can't specify my inventory file :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, my guess is that since ansible with packer uses a local connection (`-c local`), there is not need to provide an inventory file.

You just have to make sure that in your playbook, your `-hosts` line(s) contains `all` or `127.0.0.1` and it should run ok.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `hosts: all` is fine if the playbook is used exclusively for your Packer build.

If you're re-using a playbook that also needs to run against hosts specified in an inventory file, for example:

```
[web_servers]
web1.example.com
web2.example.com

[db_servers]
db.example.com
```

...then you can add the `inventory_groups` attribute to your `ansible-local` provisioner, and Packer will assign localhost to those group(s):

```
"provisioners": [ 
  { "type": "file", "source": "my_folder", "destination": "/tmp/" }, 
  { "type": "shell", "script": "provisioner.sh" }, 
  { 
    "type": "ansible-local", 
    "staging_directory": "/tmp/my_folder",
    "playbook_file": "my_folder/playbook.yml",
    "inventory_groups": "web_servers"
  }
]
```

For more details, see the **Optional** sub-section of the Packer doc for [ansible-local provisioner Configuration Reference](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible-local.html#configuration-reference)